# How to sort by a combined value of multiple columns/fields (total size of X collections) using QueryDsl and PageRequest class?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sorting, querydsl

I'm using QueryDsl and MongoDB.
This is the call that I'm making to dog repository:

```
return findAll(predicate, pageRequest);
```

I believe It's all about creating a correct PageRequest object.

What you need to know:
Entity "Dog" contains "Basic", "CertificatesAndTitles", Collection of "Show"s.
"Basic" has the pedigreeName.
"CertificatesAndTitles" holds 3 collections: championats, juniorChampions, countryChampions.
"Show" entity contains Collection of "Title".
Note that these are just some of the attributes, others do not matter. It has to be like this, someone else made it and it's a requirement.

What **WORKS** for me:

```
new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Direction.ASC, "basic.pedigreeName"))
```

This sorts dogs alphabetically by pedigreeName.
However, I have yet to implement a primary sort. In order to do that, I have to sum the sizes of championats, juniorChampions, countryChampions, titles and sort by the result.

What I've tried so far and is **NOT WORKING** (just one collection for now):

```
new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "certificatesAndTitles.championats.size()"))
new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "QDog.dog.certificatesAndTitles.championats.size()"))
new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "size(certificatesAndTitles.championats)"))
new QPageRequest(page, size, new QSort(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.DESC, QDog.dog.certificatesAndTitles.championats.size())))
```

I don't want to create additional database fields that serve as 'total counters' because it feels bad and there are more sort combinations in this project. It's just one of them.

And even if we manage to make it work, how to combine the size values of multiple collections?

I've spent quite some time looking for an answer. In SQL It'd be pretty simple but this is mongo and I have no idea how to make it in QueryDsl. Any help would be appreciated.